# How to replace NUL in vi?

Tags: regex, replace, vi

I have a NUL character in my text file. (If I do 'ga' on that character it prints NUL.) How do I replace this character with something else?

I am using GVIM on Windows.

Answer (score 8):

:%s/[\x0]//g

http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/search-for-null-td1194026.html

Comment: This is the closest I got to a solution. It doesn't match some NULs.

Answer (score -2):

`:s/\x0//g` should do the work.

Comment: Didn't work. \x is matching all valid hex characters (0-9,A-F) and \x0 matches all hex chars followed by 0.